# Woocommerce - remove the quantity arrows within the quantity box

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have customised the quantity selector to include plus/minus arrows instead.

When you click in the box though, it shows arrows. How can I remove these arrows? Can't find the code with inspect as they disappear!
They're very annoying as it offsets the centred text!

Example:
https://mr-velocity.com/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot-2022-04-22-at-11.55.09.png

Any help MUCH appreciated :)

Comment: What code are you seeing? It looks like built in increments on an input type number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to hide them as stated here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_arrow_number.asp

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```